# Receiving two-way SMS messages with Twilio and Link Inbound message with Outbound message

Tags: sms, twilio, outbound, inbound

We are using Twilio for sending outbound message to our customers.
When we send Outbound SMS to Customer then we are storing Outbound message details in our Database.

Also we have implemented Inbound SMS. So if we receive any inbound SMS from customer then we are creating inbound message record in database.

**Now our requirement is that if sent a sms to Customer and then customer replied to that outbound message then we have need to store Inbound SMS under Outbound SMS, so we can relate inbound message with Outbound message.**

Is there any way to identify in twilio that inbound message that we have received is related to which Outbound message (may be can we use any unique **identifier**)?

Thanks,

Raj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is no affordance in SMS to reply to specific messages. You can see this yourself by opening your SMS app on your phone and trying to reply to the second to last message you received from someone. It's simply not possible.

So, you can either make the assumption that if you have sent a message to a user that their next inbound message to your number is in response to that.

Or, you can use multiple numbers to send different messages, associating responses based on the number that sent/received the message.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure I work at Till Mobile.

I believe you can achieve this using our A2P SMS platform (which happens to utilize Twilio).

Till creates a unique id for the to and from phone number combination when an outbound message is sent.

When an inbound message is received it is tagged with the same unique id. In the Till API this id is called the *project_launch_guid*.

**Using the Till API**

You can get a free username and api_key via https://tillmobile.com/

**Send the outbound message**

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{
  "phone": ["phone_number"],
  "questions" : [{
      "text": "Welcome to the customer appreciation program. If you have a question please respond.",
      "webhook": "http://requestb.in/1ilpbfd1"
  }]
}' "https://platform.tillmobile.com/api/send?username=username&api_key=api_key"
```

Which returns

```
{
    "project_launch_guid": "some_guid",
    ...
}
```

**Retrieve the inbound message**

If a user later responds the message will be POST'd to the *webhook* defined above in this format including the same *project_launch_guid* returned from the *send*:

```
{
    "project_launch_guid": "some_guid",
    "participant_guid": "585897f2-2c30-43f5-8f6b-7c243e8ac4b0",
    "participant_phone_number": "phone_number",
    "question_guid": "685897f2-2c30-43f5-8f6b-7c243e8ac4b0",
    "question_text": "Welcome to the customer appreciation program. If you have a question please respond.",
    "result_guid": "885897f2-2c30-43f5-8f6b-7c243e8ac4b0",
    "result_timestamp": "2016-11-27T11:57:14.060474",
    "result_answer": "How do I redeem my points?",
    ...
}
```

Note: the webhook is optional. If it is not provided the inbound message can be retrieved via our results API:

```
curl "https://platform.tillmobile.com/api/results?username=username&api_key=api_key&project_launch_guid=some_guid"
```

Using either the webhook or results API the *project_launch_guid* can be used to tie the outbound and inbound messages together. The *result_answer* attribute value will contain the user's inbound message.

FYI We treat each *send* like a session. They persist indefinitely unless another *send* is created with the same to and from phone numbers. In that case the second *send* is queued behind the first and a configurable TTL is set on the first.

We have more documentation available here https://till.readme.io/docs/

Don't hesitate to let me know how we can assist further.